# W-marginal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Definition**

$W$ is a set of words. In a group $G$, a normal subgroup $N$ is **$W$-marginal** in $G$ if and only if $w(g_1, \cdots, g_{i-1}, g_ia, g_{i+1}, \cdots, g_r) = w(g_1, \cdots, g_{i-1}, g_i, g_{i+1}, \cdots, g_r)$ for all $g_i \in G$, $a \in N$ and all words $w(x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_r)$ in $W$. We define now **$W^*(G)$** as the largest $W$-marginal subgroup of $G$.

**Question**

I read that the $c-1$ term of the upper central series in a group $G$ is $W^*(G)$, where $W={[x_1,...,x_c]}$ but I can't prove it. I worked out the first implication, namely that $W^*(G)\leq Z_{c-1}(G)$ and I also know that $Z_{c-2}(G)\leq W^*(G)$. What about the other? I think is some strange (or maybe easy) calculation on commutator... As usually, any hints?

Comment: I think it follows from $[\gamma^i(G),Z_c(G)] \le Z_{c-i}(G)$, where $G = \gamma^1(G) \ge \cdots$ is the lower central series of $G$ (and of course $Z_k(G) = 1$ for $k \le 0$).

Comment: Yeah, I really just figure out by myself...
I'm sorry I'm too impulsive :)